# Foreach loop for model properties

Tags: asp.net, razor, foreach

I have model like this:

```
public class MyModelClass
{
   /*some properties*/
   public InnerPropertyContainer InnerContainer {get;set;}
}

public class InnerPropertyContainer
{
   public bool Soccer{get;set;}
   public bool Basketball{get;set;}
   public bool Golf{get;set;}
   /*etc...*/
}
```

In .cshtml file I want to show message like "Nothing been selected", if all properties inside InnerPropertyContainer set to False. So now I do next trick inside cshtml file:

```
@{
    bool hasSomethingSelected = false;
}

@if(Model.InnerPropertyContainer.Golf)
{
   hasSomethingSelected = true;
   /*displaying div's etc*/
}

/*doing same for each propery*/

@if(!hasSomethingSelected)
{
  <div>Nothing has been selected.</div>
}
```

It looks like little bit too "workaround" decision. Is there is any way to use something like

```
Model.InnerPropertyContainer.AnyPropertyTypeOfBool(x => x.Property == true)//pseudo code
```

Could not find any solution for that one.

Comment: you'd have to make those properties into some sort of list of properties, I think.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I forced to use Dictionary or this workaround.

Comment: it's not really a workaround, don't beat yourself up. It's just how you have to do it when you've got the data structure that you have. If you really hate it, then yes you could change your data structure. It's purely a matter of personal coding style, really.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection, to gather all boolean properties from your model, extract their values and see if any of them is true:

```
@{
    bool hasSomethingSelected = (from prop in Model.InnerPropertyContainer.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                where prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool)
                select (bool)prop.GetValue(env)).Any(p => p);

}
```

Remember to put using in your razor view:

```
@using System.Reflection
```